# HTTP Basic Auth with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, http, nsurlsession, basic-authentication, urlsession

I'm trying to implement HTTP Basic Auth with `NSURLSession`, but I run into several issues. Please read the entire question before responding, I doubt this is a duplicate of an other question.

According to the tests I've run, the behavior of `NSURLSession` is the following :

- The first request is always made without the `Authorization` header.
- If the first request fails with a `401 Unauthorized` response and a `WWW-Authenticate Basic realm=...` header, it is automatically retried.
- Before retrying the request, the session will attempt to obtain credentials by looking into the `NSURLCredentialStorage` of the session configuration or by calling the `URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` delegate method (or both).
- If credentials could be obtained the request is retried with the proper  `Authorization` header. If not it is retried without the header (which is weird because in this case, this is exactly the same request).
- If the second request succeeds, the task is transparently reported as successful and you're not even notified that the request was attempted twice. If not, the failure of the second request is reported (but not the first).

The problem I have with this behavior is that I am uploading large files to my server through multipart requests, so when the request is attempted twice, the entire `POST` body is sent twice which is a terrible overhead.

I have tried to manually add the `Authorization` header to the `httpAdditionalHeaders` of the session configuration, but it works only if the property is set *before* the session is created. Attempting to modify `session.configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders` afterwards doesn't work. Also the documentation clearly says that the `Authorization` header should not be set manually.

---

**So my question is**: If I need to start the session before I obtain the credentials and If I want to be sure that requests are always made with the proper  `Authorization` header the first time, how do I do ?

---

Here is a code sample that I've used for my tests. You can reproduce all the behaviors I've described above with it.

Note that in order to be able to see the double requests you wil need to either use your own http server and log the requests or connect through a proxy that logs all requests (I've used [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com) for this)

```
class URLSessionTest: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate
{
    static let shared = URLSessionTest()

    func start()
    {
        let requestURL = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/username/password")!
        let credential = URLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence: .forSession)
        let protectionSpace = URLProtectionSpace(host: "httpbin.org", port: 443, protocol: NSURLProtectionSpaceHTTPS, realm: "Fake Realm", authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic)

        let useHTTPHeader = false
        let useCredentials = true
        let useCustomCredentialsStorage = false
        let useDelegateMethods = true

        let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        if (useHTTPHeader) {
            let authData = "\(credential.user!):\(credential.password!)".data(using: .utf8)!
            let authValue = "Basic " + authData.base64EncodedString()
            sessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": authValue]
        }
        if (useCredentials) {
            if (useCustomCredentialsStorage) {
                let urlCredentialStorage = URLCredentialStorage()
                urlCredentialStorage.set(credential, for: protectionSpace)
                sessionConfiguration.urlCredentialStorage = urlCredentialStorage
            } else {
                sessionConfiguration.urlCredentialStorage?.set(credential, for: protectionSpace)
            }
        }

        let delegate = useDelegateMethods ? self : nil
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: nil)

        self.makeBasicAuthTest(url: requestURL, session: session) {
            self.makeBasicAuthTest(url: requestURL, session: session) {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 61.0) {
                    self.makeBasicAuthTest(url: requestURL, session: session) {}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func makeBasicAuthTest(url: URL, session: URLSession, completion: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print("response : \(response)")
            }
            if let data = data {
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) {
                    print("json : \(json)")
                } else if data.count > 0, let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("string : \(string)")
                } else {
                    print("data : \(data)")
                }
            }
            if let error = error {
                print("error : \(error)")
            }
            print()
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: completion)
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    @objc(URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:)
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void)
    {
        print("Session authenticationMethod: \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)")
        if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic) {
            let credential = URLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence: .forSession)
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
        } else {
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        }
    }

    @objc(URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:)
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Swift.Void)
    {
        print("Task authenticationMethod: \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)")
        if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic) {
            let credential = URLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence: .forSession)
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
        } else {
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

*Note 1*: When making multiple requests in a row to the same endpoint, the behavior I've described above concerns only the first request. Subsequent requests are tried with the proper `Authorization` header the first time. However, if you wait some time (about 1 minute), the session will return to the default behavior (first request tried twice).

*Note 2*: This is not directly related, but using a custom `NSURLCredentialStorage` for the `urlCredentialStorage` of the session configuration doesn't seem to work. Only using the default value (which is the shared `NSURLCredentialStorage` according to the documentation) works.

*Note 3*: I've tried using `Alamofire`, but since it's based on `NSURLSession`, it behaves in the exact same way.

Comment: Why not have the first request always do no work other than get a proper Authorization header? The next request (and onward) does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Try not overriding `didReceiveChallenge`

Comment: @GlennRay That's an ugly solution that I don't even want to consider. Still consumes bandwidth for no good reason and as I said, it's not just the very first request of the session, but the first request every time you stay about 1min without sending anything, so that's also terribly impractical no implement.

Comment: @RunLoop Tried that. Also try to use every possible answer in the completion handler. Doesn't work.

Comment: Try setting up NSURLSession with the ephemeral option and only set authorization with the additional headers option.

Comment: As I said, using `httpAdditionalHeaders` only works if the property is set before the session is created. I need to be able to provide credentials after the session is created.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, the server should respond with an error long before the client finishes sending the body.  However, in many high-level server-side languages, this is difficult, and there's no guarantee that the upload will stop even if you do so.

The real problem is that you're performing a large upload using a single POST request.  That make authentication problematic, and also prevents any sort of useful continuation of uploads if the connection drops midway through the upload. Chunking the upload basically solves all of your issues:

- For your first request, send only the amount that will fit without adding additional Ethernet packets, i.e. compute your typical header size, mod by 1500 bytes, add a few tens of bytes for good measure, subtract from 1500, and hard-code that size for your first chunk.  At most, you've wasted a few packets.
- For subsequent chunks, crank the size up.
- When a request fails, ask the server how much it got, and retry from where the upload left off.
- Issue a request to tell the server when you've finished uploading.
- Periodically purge partial uploads on the server side with a cron job or whatever.

That said, if you don't have control over the server side, the usual workaround is to sent an authenticated GET request right before your POST request.  This minimizes wasted packets while still mostly working as long as the network is reliable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm already doing chunked uploads, but chunks themselves are still big. For now I found a way to inject the proper headers into every request so it's working. I was hoping for a solution at the `URLSession` level. I find it very surprising that I can't configure authentication upfront and instead I have to wait for a request to fail. I feel I've missed something on this API.

Comment: So why not just configure the first chunk to be tiny—say 500 bytes?

Comment: Chunks are fixed in size and I don't want to rewrite server side code because of an iOS bug :)